# Me Crashea mi proyecto Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas mi error es desde que inicia el gradle no avisa error ni nada ejecuta el emulador y inicia el launch activity y crashea y dice que se a detenido.

Ya probe los siguentes recomendaciones:

- Reinicar el proyecto(cache ,build )
- Iniciar en frio el dispositivo (emulador)
- Instalar android studio desde cero y crea un proyecto default igual crashea

Error en concreto:
**Emulator: emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Critical: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined (qrc:/html/js/location-mock-web-channel.js:130, (null))  (Creo no estoy seguro)**

Adjunto fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LogCat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Las causas pueden ser diversas, debes Agregar el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat,.

Comment: Ahora lo pongo :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en el manifest debes poner el id de tu app que añadiste en admob.com

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

y en el gradle lo siguiente

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```

y añadir la dependencia

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.1'
```

Comment: Tengo justo el mismo problema, he intentado hacer lo que dice @ruckzake pero no se donde encontrar el id de admon.com, si admob.com busqué y era algo relacionado con publicidad.